# curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired

Tags: ssl, curl, debian

My PHP application as some issue to communicate with API or other serveur (FTP...).

When I watch the logs, I see that it came from a problème with CURL.

I tried to fix the issue :

- Renew certificate
- Change certificate

Nothing change

Here is a command line I lunch in terminal (Debian) :

> curl --location 'https://hooks.slack.com/services///' --header 'Content-Type: text/plain' --data '{"channel": "#team-it", "text": "Hello, world"}'

But I got this error :

```
    curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

Even if my cert if renew...

Any idea how I can fix that ?

Comment: If the problem happens when accessing **another** URL (like hooks.slack.com in the example), keep in mind that you need to change **their** certificate and not your own to overcome the problem

Comment: Same problem with other URL (https://api.nextendweb.com)...

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Looks like your local certificate storage is outdated?

Comment: I started hitting this also.

Answer (score 0):

you may use `-k, --insecure           Allow insecure server connections`

curl --location --insecure 'https://hooks.slack.com/services///' --header 'Content-Type: text/plain' --data '{"channel": "#team-it", "text": "Hello, world"}'

Comment: That gonna fix the problem in terminal only, but not in PHP :)